# FXML set TableView column resize policy

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-2, fxml

How can I set a TableView's resize policy from FXML? I tired this way, but it's not working:

```
<TableView layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" prefWidth="674.0" prefHeight="668.0" fx:id="tableView" fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn text="First Name" />
        <TableColumn text="Last Name" />
        <TableColumn text="Email Address" />
    </columns>    
</TableView>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To set columnresize policy for tableview using fxml , you have to use `<columnResizePolicy>` tag . This will work on javafx 2.2 and later..

```
<TableView>
  <columnResizePolicy><TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/></columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

Reference :

[Defining TableView columnResizePolicy property with fxml](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19228?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#issue-tabs)

Comment: Thanks it works! Thats a damn "interresting" syntax here. I see why they used that way but well, it's ugly. But works... :)

Comment: If I use the tag as you proposed I get the error message "Unable to coerce javafx.scene.control.TableView to javafx.util.Callback" in my FXML editor. Any hint?

Comment: This seems to only prevent setting column prefWidths now, and does not prevent user resizing