# How to get TableHeaderRow from TableView nowadays in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I saw examples on how to get table header in many places with code

```
TableHeaderRow header = (TableHeaderRow) tableView.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
```

like here: [How to prevent TableView from doing TableColumn re-order in javaFX 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202782/how-to-prevent-tableview-from-doing-tablecolumn-re-order-in-javafx-8)

But this code returns `null` for me.

How to reach `TableHeaderRow` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TableHeaderRow` is created by the `Skin` and the default `Skin` is not created until css is applied.

You could call [`applyCss`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--) after adding the `TableView` to a `Scene` and access the `TableHeaderRow` after this call.

Alternatively listen for changes in the `Skin` and execute that code after the skin has been set.

Furthermore I'd recommend using `TableViewSkinBase.getTableHeaderRow` to retrieve the header row instead of using `lookup` (you're using `com.sun` packages anyway).

```
tableView.skinProperty().addListener((a, b, newSkin) -> {
    TableHeaderRow headerRow = ((TableViewSkinBase) newSkin).getTableHeaderRow();
    ...
});
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken the getTableHeaderRow method is no longer visible in JavaFX11

Answer (score 3):

lookup("TableHeaderRow"); works, but it needs called after the table is rendered or it will return null