# TreeTableColumn.visible : A bound value cannot be set

Tags: java, javafx-8, treetableview, jxtreetable, property-binding

I make a simple JavaFX application. In this application there is a treetable with 2 columns and a check box. If check box is selected column 2 will be visible, otherwise not visible. To do this I bound tree table column visible property to checkbox selected property. When I click the check box column state change but at the same time gives.

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: TreeTableColumn.visible : A
>   bound value cannot be set.

If I use bidirectional binding I don't get this error. But I don't need bidirectional binding. Is it a bug or I don't use bind correctly? Please use below code to reproduce this error. I use jdk1.8.0_111.

**JavaFXApplication.java**

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**FXMLDocumentController.java**

```
package test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TreeTableView<?> table;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox box;
    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<?, ?> c2;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        c2.visibleProperty().bind(box.selectedProperty());
    }    

}
```

**FXMLDocument.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="390.0" prefWidth="452.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" fx:controller="javafxapplication2.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
      <TreeTableView fx:id="table" layoutX="2.0" prefHeight="390.0" prefWidth="149.0">
        <columns>
          <TreeTableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
          <TreeTableColumn fx:id="c2" prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" visible="false" />
        </columns>
      </TreeTableView>
      <CheckBox fx:id="box" layoutX="234.0" layoutY="77.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `visible="false"` attribute from the FXML?  I would have assumed FXML properties are set before calling the `initialize` method, but perhaps it's the other way around...

Comment: @sillyfly I also think this and remove from fxml file but result the same

Comment: `TableView` and `TreeTableView` support a drop-down menu where you can choose which columns are visible. Probably supporting this, even if you don't use it, causes a call to `setVisible` on the columns somewhere (and hence the error). I would just replace the binding with a listener on the check box selection state, even though the binding is a bit more elegant.

Comment: @James_D yes you are write I got this error because of column visible property already bound implicitly to menu button even if you do not use this button.

Comment: so we can not use bind method?

Comment: @sakit It appears not. Just use a listener instead.

Comment: ok. Thanks @James_D

Comment: Does a bugreport exist for this already? I think that this behaviour should not exists. Bindings are there to be used and not throw errors where none should be imo.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 I don't know

Comment: I got the same problem, but only with Java 8, and could not reproduce the problem with Java 11. It seems there is a bug report for this problem that was fixed in Java 9. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136468.

Answer (score 0):

I think this actually is not a bug. It's definitely mysterious and unexpected behavior though. Part of the problem is that the binding conflict is coming from [TableHeaderRow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/TableHeaderRow.html), which is [created by the skin at display time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38720992/1027800).

The `TableHeaderRow` is responsible for rendering all the column headers, and it includes this built-in button for a menu that, by default, is a radio selection list of columns to show/hide:

[image: TableView with column header button]

As a result, the `TableHeaderRow` creates a bidirectional binding between these menu entries' selection state and each column's visible property.

It actually is possible to undo this binding but I found it annoying since the `TableHeaderRow` is `null` until the `TableView` is displayed. But, adapting [this solution to access the TableHeaderRow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27834038/1027800), we can do something like:

```
      TableHeaderRow headerRow = ((TableViewSkinBase) tableView.getSkin()).getTableHeaderRow();
      try {

        // get columnPopupMenu field
        Field privateContextMenuField = TableHeaderRow.class.getDeclaredField("columnPopupMenu");

        // make field public
        privateContextMenuField.setAccessible(true);

        // get context menu
        ContextMenu contextMenu = (ContextMenu) privateContextMenuField.get(headerRow);

        for (MenuItem menuItem : contextMenu.getItems()) {
          // Assuming these will be CheckMenuItems in the default implementation
          BooleanProperty selectedProperty = ((CheckMenuItem) menuItem).selectedProperty();

          // In theory these menu items are in parallel with the columns, but I just brute forced it to test
          for (TableColumn<?, ?> tableColumn : tableView.getColumns()) {
            // Unlink the column's visibility with the menu item
            tableColumn.visibleProperty().unbindBidirectional(selectedProperty);
          }
        }

      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }

      // Not strictly necessary but we don't want to be misleading :-p
      tableView.setTableMenuButtonVisible(false);
```

But here's the kicker: you have to do this every time a column's visibility changes, because the `TableHeaderRow` has a listener that rebuilds the menu, and re-links the properties, every time a column is shown.

You could, of course, find a way to disable that listener.. but clearly this is already ridiculous and probably unnecessary.

Anyway, as you noted:

> If I use bidirectional binding I don't get this error. But I don't need bidirectional binding.

I think the second statement isn't technically true: your use case doesn't require bidirectional binding, but it is actually appropriate here since there *are* other properties already linked with a column's visibility.

So, I would use bidirectional binding.