# automatically resize TableColumn of TableColumn in TableView with JavaFX -8

Tags: java, resize, tableview, javafx-8, tablecolumn

When I generate a table in JavaFX, the columns are too large and I want to resize them when it appears on my app in order to reduce them.
I read those articles on stackOverflow which are usefull but they didn't help me : [javafx column in tableview auto fit size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650787/javafx-column-in-tableview-auto-fit-size) ; [JavaFX TableColumn resize to fit cell content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284437/javafx-tablecolumn-resize-to-fit-cell-content/38686413).
Indeed, unlike theme, I have columns in my columns and it doesn't work.
For information those columns react as the same way, if we double click on them they resize automatically.
I tried to reproduce those solutions like that :

```
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; 
    import java.lang.reflect.Method; import java.util.List; 
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;   
    import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin;
    import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener; 
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList; 
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn; 
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class GUIUtils {     
       private static Method columnToFitMethod;

       static {         
            try {           
               columnToFitMethod = TableViewSkin.class.getDeclaredMethod("resizeColumnToFitContent",TableColumn.class,int.class);
            columnToFitMethod.setAccessible(true);      
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {             
                e.printStackTrace();        
            }   
        }

       public static <S> void autoFitTable(TableView<S> tableView) {         
            tableView.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Object>() {
                  @Override             
                  public void onChanged(Change<?> c) {
                        for (TableColumn column : tableView.getColumns()) {
                            try {
                                List<TableColumn<S, ?>> columns = (List<TableColumn<S, ?>>) column.getColumns.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                                for (TableColumn col : columns) {
                                    columnToFitMethod.invoke(tableView.getSkin(), col, -1);
                                }
                                columnToFitMethod.invoke(tableView.getSkin(), column, -1);
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }           
                  }         
           });  
       } 
}
```

During my second iteration for child column, I have :

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   myPackage.GUIUtils$1.onChanged(GUIUtils.java:37) 
>   .
>   . 
>   . 
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin.resizeColumnToFitContent(TableViewSkin.java:257)
>     ... 80 more

Do you have an idea of what can I do ?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested, my solution works but some of my column are not visible and that's why I have my exception.
Just put if(col.isVisible()) and that's fine !