# How to set TableColumn to the width it needs?

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

In a JavaFX TableView, each column can be resized "automatically" to the minimum with needed by double clicking on the separators between the columns.

I would like to have this behaviour automatically. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Sedrick Thank your for pointing out this question! I am not sure yet if it really helps, but it seems to be a duplicate of this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284437/javafx-tablecolumn-resize-to-fit-cell-content/38686413

Comment: Have you tired anything? Where is your code.