# Controller For FXML based TableView Pagination

Tags: javafx

I have a customized TableView defined in an FXML and the table works fine so far. The code is something like the followings:

```
<FitWidthTableView fx:id="dataDisplayView" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="380.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="rowColumn" maxWidth="50.0" prefWidth="30.0" sortable="false" style="-fx-alignment: CENTER_RIGHT;" text="Row" />
        ...
</FitWidthTableView>
```

Now, I need to add the Pagination due to a huge amount of data (from a DB). It would be great if I can wrap around the TableView tag with the Pagination tag. I find a sample with the approach as the following

```
    <Pagination fx:id="pagination" layoutX="2.0" layoutY="188.0" prefHeight="275.0" prefWidth="912.0">
    <fx:define>
        <FitWidthTableView fx:id="dataDisplayView" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                           maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="380.0"
                           VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="rowColumn" maxWidth="50.0" prefWidth="30.0" sortable="false"
                             style="-fx-alignment: CENTER_RIGHT;" text="Row"/>
               ...
            </columns>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets left="1.0" right="1.0"/>
            </VBox.margin>
        </FitWidthTableView>
    </fx:define>
</Pagination>
```

while almost all examples of TableView with Pagination are done without FXML.

I, however, don't see the pagination controller code sample which shall do a few things: determine the number of pages, specify the page size, and populate data to the table. Can someone advise on the subject?

My controller is something like the followings:

```
public class DataViewerController implements Initializable {


@FXML
private Pagination pagination ;

@FXML
private FitWidthTableView<OutputData> dataDisplayView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<OutputData, Integer> rowColumn;

…

@Autowired
private OutputDataRepository outputDataRepository;

@Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
@FXML
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
  …
  
  }
…
}
```

How to populate data with the above code structure?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. The controller code is just Java,  so it would be the same as any examples you have found that don't use FXML. Can you create and post a [mre]?

Comment: I add the controller code snap to my post to clarify my question. I can't see how to populate the data to the table after adding pagination to the code. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what a `FitWidthTableView` is. With a regular `TableView` you would just do `dataDisplayView.setItems(...)` as normal. With a `Pagination`, you presumably want to set the items to a sublist of the full data list in the page factory. Again, there is absolutely no difference between doing this in your controller code and doing this in a JavaFX application which doesn't use FXML, so it's not at all clear what your question is. Any pagination example should show you how to do this.

Comment: The class is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284437/javafx-tablecolumn-resize-to-fit-cell-content/69961976#69961976 to allow a full display of extremely long data. And the previous code have the data populated in the public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) method with dataDisplayView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(ll)); The same code doesn't get me a table at all, but only pagination on the bottom.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25424208/2189127) is an example showing how to use a table view in a pagination.

Comment: *"The same code doesn't get me a table at all, but only pagination on the bottom."*. Yes, of course. You wrapped it in [`<fx:define>`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#define_elements)

Comment: Thanks very much for the reference. I will try it and see how it works out. I am confused with the createPage returned data type. In the code sample, it is Node. I have seen the Text as the returned data type in another code sample. Any insight?

Comment: A `TableView` _is a_ `Node`.

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. The only "catch" about using a `TableView` in a `Pagination` in FXML is that you have to provide the `TableView` from the page factory, so it can't be included anywhere else in the scene graph. The way to define it in FXML without it being part of the scene graph is to wrap it in `<fx:define>`. You've already done that, so the rest is all just standard pagination code, which I linked in the previous comment.

Comment: @trashgod If TableView is Node, why the createPage doesn't return a tableveiw but wraps it with BorderPane?

Comment: There's no real need for it to wrap it in a `BorderPane`; there is a comment to that effect below the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works well so far to my test.

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#overview), any [`Pagination`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html#pageCountProperty) property can be initialized in your FXML:

```
<Pagination pageCount="8" currentPageIndex="3" …/>
```

More likely, you'll derive the values based on your actual data. Your implementation of the `pageFactory()` should set the desired partition on the table and return a table view, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25424208/2189127).

> I want to keep the `TableView` in the FXML.

As, @James_D comments, the `TableView` declaration is irrelevant to the `pageFactory()`. As a concrete example, start from the complete example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69651076/230513) and substitute the following FXML declarations in `center`:

```
<center>
    <Pagination fx:id="pager" currentPageIndex="1"/>
    <fx:define>
        <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="60.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="itemName" text="Item Name" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="pricePerUnit" text="Price Per Unit" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="quantity" text="Quantity" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="amount" text="Amount" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </fx:define>
</center>
```

In the controller, inject the `pager` and `initialize()` it:

```
@FXML
Pagination pager;
…
//tableView.setItems(objList);
pager.setPageCount(objList.size());
pager.setPageFactory((Integer pageIndex) -> createPage(pageIndex));
```

The following factory assigns a single row to the `tableView` and returns it:

```
public TableView<TestModel> createPage(int page) {
    tableView.getItems().setAll(objList.get(page));
    return tableView;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have seen the sample. I want to keep the tableview in the FXML because there are some style settings and I don't want to create a CSS file just for the table.

Comment: @vic Again, the fact that the table is defined in FXML makes absolutely no difference to how the page factory is defined (and other configurations of the pagination). I don't understand why you keep raising this point; it's irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to JavaFX.