# Using a variable from a java file in an FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm creating a stage that I've made in scenebuilder and I want some of the sizes in there to be dependent on the size of the monitor. However, in scenebuilder, when setting pref width/height, I can only write a number or "USE_COMPUTED_SIZE".
I know that I can get the dimensions of the screen by using the following code;

```
Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();

    @FXML
    double windowHeight = screenBounds.getHeight()/2;
    @FXML
    double windowWidth = screenBounds.getHeight()/2;
```

is there a way to use these variables "**windowHeight**" and "**windowWidth**" in the FXML file. Like:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="windowHeight" prefWidth="windowWidth" stylesheets="@defaultStyle.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Menu">
```

(The variables "**windowHeight**" and "**windowWidth**" are declared in Menu.java)

Another preferred way to be able to do it would be if I could directly set the width and height to a variable within scenebuilder.

Perhaps, even better would be if I could set all values within scenebuilder to be by preferred ratio rather that size, so that later on, when resizing the stage, everything would change with it.

I have tried to later set the width and height of the stage when loading it but it didn't really work.

Comment: You can [_define_](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#define_elements) arbitrary elements, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74480486/230513), but I would advocate using the computed size in a responsive layout.

Comment: *”Perhaps, even better would be if I could set all values within scenebuilder to be by preferred ratio rather that size, so that later on, when resizing the stage, everything would change with it.”* This is what you should do. Just choose appropriate layout panes that implement this behavior; it is exactly what they are for. `AnchorPane`, which does not really implement a responsive layout, is rarely the correct choice.

Comment: your first code snippet would be plain wrong: fields annotated with fxml are supposed to be injected by the loader, they _must not_ be initialized - it's a one-way road. As already suggested in the other comments: learn all about layouts, choose an appropriate one. when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem

Comment: Another [example of `fx:define`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705654/bind-font-size-in-javafx). See the usage of the `Measurement` class in my answer.  Though, please heed the recommendations in other comments. I wouldn’t use the define mechanism like this unless I really needed to as it would complicate things for me.

Comment: This looks like a case where you are attempting to take the wrong approach to accomplish a task. My guess is that you should do this while loading an FXML. If this is the loading of the first FXML, it should be done in the `Main`.  `Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();        
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginScreen.fxml"));        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, screenBounds.getWidth()/2, screenBounds.getHeight()/2);`

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can initialize the bounds of AnchorPane in the controller class instead of using variables ,since it is not allowed to be.
Perhaps you should implement the `Controller` class with `Initializable` class to over ride the `initialize` method.
As names suggests , you can initialize the component of the fxml file using that method.
And of course you can inside that method set the bounds by `root.setPrefHeight(customVariable);`.

#### Full code:

`import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

@fxml
public AnchorPane root;
public int height = 180;
public int width = 200;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    root.setPrefHeight(height);
    root.setPrefWidth(width);
    }
}`