# Set table width to the accumulated width of all columns

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to get the width of a TableView object as wide as the accumulated sums of all TableColumns, so that the Table is fully shown without a scrollbar.
The table is inside a grid Layout, and i tried getting the width of all columns together with the following code:

```
private double getTableWidth(TableView dataTable){
        double totalWidth = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.getColumns().size(); i++){
            totalWidth += ((TableColumn) dataTable.getColumns().get(i)).getWidth();
        }
        return totalWidth;
}
```

But somehow the width for each column is 80, even if they look different wide.

To set the width of the table i use the following:

```
dataTable.setMinWidth(getTableWidth(dataTable));
```

Note:
I start with a TableView-Object with the following code:

```
children>
      <TableView fx:id="dataTable" prefHeight="451.0" prefWidth="701.0" />
   </children>
```

and fill the table by creating TableColumns without a width parameter or anything.

Picture of the current State:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the column resize policy to `constrained-resize`, in this way you will fill all the width available divided for each column.

You can do it using FXML:

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="78.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="396.0">
    <columnResizePolicy><TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/></columnResizePolicy>
    <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Column X" />
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Column X" />
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

You can do it programmatically:

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

You may want to look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484960/table-column-wont-take-full-size-of-the-table-view-in-javafx)